# CentOS: How to group two partitions to one document root?

Tags: filesystems, partition, mount

i have 2 partitions in my cloud server. And i want to group two of these become one as Apache document root.

Because i have some websites and data is around 80GB.

Does it possible?

```
/dev/vda1       92891468 1475352  86681236   2% /
devtmpfs         1931888       0   1931888   0% /dev
tmpfs            1941036       0   1941036   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs            1941036   16628   1924408   1% /run
tmpfs            1941036       0   1941036   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/vdb1       51472864   53272  48781872   1% /mnt/blockstorage
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a loopback-filesystem on each device, then group those into a raid-0.  However, why not get an appropriately sized filesystem for your 80G instead of a hacked together pseudo-device?

Comment: Because of the package that i ordered, it has only 90G SSG storage. I have to order more 50G space. Im going to read about loopback-filesystem. So, if i mount `/mnt/blockstorage` to `/var/www/html/a_web_here` to store one of my website, does it work?

Comment: Yes, or you could mkdir /mnt/blockstorage/a_web_here and ln -s  /mnt/blockstorage/a_web_here /var/www/html/a_web_here (and ensure FollowSymlinks is enabled in apache) to avoid having to remount.